# ASP.NET 4 Response.Redirect not working from / but is from /index.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, response

I have a very basic test page, with a button and on the button click a call to

```
Response.Redirect("b.aspx")
```

This works fine when the page is loaded as `http://myhost/index.aspx`. However when the same page loads via `http://myhost/`, the redirect doesn't work (the same page just reloads like a normal postback).

The only thing I've been able to determine is that the response code for `/` is 200, whereas for `/index.aspx` it's correctly 302

The server is IIS7 running ASP.NET4.

I have tried using true and false as the second param in `Redirect()` but no difference.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Did you try response.redirect("/b.aspx") ?

Comment: Thanks but using /b.aspx didn't work either - although not a bad thought...

Comment: If anyone cares it turned out to be a problem with a Telerik module elsewhere in the app.

Comment: i faced the same problem here, could you guide me to the solution,plz

Answer (score 0):

Index.aspx is not a default homepage for ASPX.

Try default.apx when you try to just type www.yoursite.com it will load your default.aspx

Hope this helps